# c++ base constructor lvalue to parameter

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor, composite, lvalue

I played a bit around with composite-patterns and inheritance in c++.
It shouldn't be something special so i coded that a component has a parent as composite, the composite should derrived from component and use the constructor from it's base class (Component). But then i got following error:

> "Cannot convert lvalue of type 'Composite*' to parameter type 'Composite*'"

Researched a bit and found out what lvalues/rvalues etc. are but didn't find anything about a "parameter" type. Is a parameter type a rvalue?
 Is it possible to convert a lvalue to a parameter type?

Here is my code as a smaller version:

```
class Component {
private:
  Composite* parent;
public:
  Component(Composite* parent) {
    this->parent = parent;
  }
};
class Composite : public Component {
public:
  Composite(Composite* parent) : Component(parent) /* <-- Error */ { }
};
```

Comment: After fixing the forward declaration, and adding the missing semicolons, the shown code compiles just fine, as is. There's nothing wrong with the shown code. Obviously, instead of providing a [mcve] of the real code with the issue, this is fantasy code. Fail.

Comment: fixed the semicolons and tried that code... but got still an error

Comment: What part of "fixing the forward declaration" you didn't originally understand?

Comment: sry ... i thought "forward declaration" means to define the methods in the class ... so i didn't changed the code on this part ... but thanks richard hodges i understand now what it means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments in corrected code.

```
class Composite;  // <- _declare_ the idea of a Composite class here

class Component {
private:
    Composite* parent;
public:
    Component(Composite* parent) {
        this->parent = parent;
    }
};

class Composite               // <- _define_ it here
        : public Component {
public:
    Composite(Composite* parent) : Component(parent) /* <-- no error */ { }
};
```

Comment: thx! so i have always to declare the derrived class before the base class if i use the derrived class in the base class ... but what actually means a "parameter type"?

Comment: Composite must have been "declared" before it is first "used". i.e. when you mention a type, the compiler must have already been told that it exists - even if you haven't yet described how it looks.

Comment: ok make sense thx... i also looked up what a "parameter type" is but i don't understand what it has to do with "lvalues" ... parameter type is just the variable-type of a specific parameter or am i wrong? so i do understand that a parameter can be a lvalue or rvalue (if you use "const" for example)